# Place group of buttons in top right corner using SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

So I'm having some issues with SwiftUI and I can't figure out how to properly place an HStack (*4 Buttons*) in the top right corner, so I wanted to reach out for some help.

**Expected Output**:
Have the HStack be shown in the top right corner of the screen.

**Current Output**:
[image]

Here is the code that I got:

```
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            VStack {

                // MARK: - CATEGORY BUTTON (MAP PIN IS CLICKED)
                // @TODO: FILTERING IS BROKEN, NEEDS TO BE FIXED
                Button(action: {

                }) //: END Button


                // MARK: - FAVORITE BUTTON (MAP PIN IS CLICKED)
//                if mainViewModel.selectedItemId != 0 {
                    Button(action: {

                    }) //: END Button


                    // MARK: - GPS BUTTON (MAP PIN IS CLICKED)
//                    if locationManager.lastLocation != nil {

                        Button(action: {

                        }) //: END Button


                        // MARK: - USER LOCATION BUTTON (MAP PIN IS CLICKED)
                        Button(action: {

                        }) //: END Button
//                    }
//                }
            } //: END VStack
            .background {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                    .fill(Color(uiColor: .systemBackground))
            }
            .tint(Color(uiColor: .secondaryLabel))
        } //: END HStack
        .padding()
```

All help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

Wrap your `HStack` in another `VStack` and add a `Spacer()` `View` below the `HStack` to push it up to the top of the screen:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                VStack {
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        
                    }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "globe")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                        .padding(10)
                        
                    })
                    Button(action: {
                        
                    }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "car")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                        .padding(10)
                        
                    })
                    Button(action: {
                        
                    }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "house")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                        .padding(10)
                        
                    })
                    Button(action: {
                        
                    }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "clock")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                        .padding(10)
                        
                    })

                } //: END VStack
                .background {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                        .fill(Color(uiColor: .systemBackground))
                        .tint(Color(uiColor: .secondaryLabel))
                }
                .padding(10)
            } //: END HStack
            Spacer()
        } //: End VStack
        .background(Color.blue.ignoresSafeArea())
    }
}
```

[image: UI running in simulator]

Comment: Thanks vacawama, this worked out perfectly! I'll have to look into what caused the extra VStack to adjust it as so.